# MSBuild Failing in VS2013 Only

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

When I build with VS2013, I get the following in my Output window (Diagnostic logging on):

```
> 2>Target "ValidateMSBuildToolsVersion" skipped. Previously built
> unsuccessfully. 2>Done executing task "MSBuild" -- FAILED. (TaskId:75)
> 2>Done building target "ResolveProjectReferences" in project
> "App.Tests.csproj" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:122) 2>Target
> "_CheckForCompileOutputs: (TargetId:123)" in file "C:\Program Files
> (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from
> project "C:\PROJECTS\App\App.Tests\App.Tests.csproj"
> (target "_CleanGetCurrentAndPriorFileWrites" depends on it): 2>Done
> building target "_CheckForCompileOutputs" in project
> "App.Tests.csproj".: (TargetId:123)
```

There isn't any indication as to what's failing though.  All references resolve.  What could be causing this?  VS2015 builds fine.

Top of CSProj:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.0.1\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.0.1\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Basically seems to say 'Target "ValidateMSBuildToolsVersion" failed', what is the project's ToolsVersion ? Might be higher than what the msbuild version for VS2013 accepts.

Comment: @stijn thanks! How do I determine that?

Comment: Open project in text editor, should be on second line

Comment: Btw only reference I found for this (on the internet) is https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/build/NuGetAdditionalFiles/Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props

Comment: @stijn thanks for the help.  I updated the question with the first few lines of my csproj.

Comment: See link: it seems to require 14.0 (or higher). Maybe if you just change it to that you can build with VS2103 as well, not sure

Comment: I have another project that builds fine with the same exact top few lines, so I don't think that's it. @stijn

Comment: @stijn just tested - still fails :(

Comment: yeah I also cannot reproduce it, starting from a fresh project, so something has to be different in the project which fails.. I can 'force' the error to occur by `msbuild my.csproj /p:BuildingProject=true` though, but I don't know which component would set that property

Comment: I also could not reproduce this issue with the same top of CSProj. According to the error log, this issue seem to be related to the target "ResolveProjectReferences", could you please double check the references in the project? Or you can create a new project with that top of csproj, then build the project, check if it works fine.

Comment: @Leo-MSFT Thank you - it does, and all references are fine.  Is there any way to see detailed output around why references aren't resolving?  This is a quite complex solution with lots of folks collaborating so moving everything over to a new project is not an option :(

Comment: @SB2055, yes, that will be a very troublesome thing. How about change the log in the output window (Detailed logging on)? And you can try to build each project in the solution separately, check if all projects build without any error.

Comment: @Leo-MSFT I have logging set to diagnostic verbosity - is this what you're referring to?  As for building separately - I have two projects.  B depends on A and only B fails due to this references issue.

Comment: @SB2055, "B depends on A and only B fails due to this references issue." That is reason for your solution build error, you need to resolve this references issue for project B. If you could not resolve it, you could share the error message to us, we will help you resolve this references issue.

Comment: @Leo-MSFT - clearly.  The problem is that there is no actionable output for this reference error.  I've provided everything I see.  Again I ask - `Is there any way to see detailed output around why references aren't resolving?`

Comment: As far as I know the answer is No. As a workaround for this issue,  you can double check the references of project B, or you can create a new project, add the references of project B one by one, check if it build successfully.